# How to correlate statistics empirical rule to P value?

Tags: empirical-likelihood

I have data from 2 tools which indicate performance, golden tool and new tool. 
I can calculate mean value and standard deviation value for each of these 2 samples.
I want to quantify if the new tool performance is within 1-sigma or more than 1-sigma of golden tool.
So I intend to setup the test as below:
Null hypothesis = new tool performance is within 1-sigma of golden tool
Alternative hypothesis = new tool performance is not within 1-sigma of golden tool.

I want to perform 2-sample t test.
From this test result, how can I tell whether the new tool performance is within or more than 1-sigma of the golden tool?

Is there other method to quantify whether the new tool performance is within or more than 1-sigma of golden tool?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is based on a false exposition of hypothesis testing, and you have not even been clear on what test you are applying and what the hypotheses of the test are.  You will need to understand and explain the test better before this question can be posed in a meaningful way.  In relation to your title question, it is worth noting that the p-value is a function that maps the data to a value between zero and one.  Hence, the p-value will generally correlate with other statistical measures of the data that are related to the test.  The specific relationship depends on the test.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking, but I'll offer a possible suggestion.  Cohen's d is used to indicate the difference between two means relative to the standard deviation (sd).  It is simply the difference of the means divided by the sd.  The sd is usually pooled, and there a couple of different ways to pool the sd's.  In some situations, people will use the sd of only one of the samples.  A Cohen's d of 0.5 indicates that the means differ by one-half of one sd, and so on.  It is not, however, a statistical test.  It is an effect size statistic.

Answer (score 1):

The regular t-test cannot do this for you; that is a test that the means are equal. What you want seems to be a test of equivalence and, in your case, you can use TOST - two one sided t-tests.

These have been discussed here before. See the tags [TOST](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tost) and [equivalence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equivalence).